# Condición para Checkbox en vista asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un checkbox en una vista para mandar "tickets" de apoyo, y al momento de darle click en un check que dice "Si" pasa por un if que al momento de de sea true ejecute el codigo dentro del if.

```
string checkBox = Request.Form.GetValues("CheckSi")[0];
                    

                    if (checkBox == "True")
                    {
                        //codigo a ejecutar
                    }
```

Y en la vista tengo un simple checkBox

```
<div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Enviar correo de confirmación")<br />
                            <span>Sí:</span> @Html.CheckBox("CheckSi")
                            <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;  No:</span> @Html.CheckBox("CheckNo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "check"})
                        </div>
```

¿Hay otra forma de pasar el checked de la vista al controlador?

Ya intente con un simple Request.Form["CheckSi"].value() pero no me funciona.

Comment: Verifica los nombres de lo que renderiza el `@Html.Checkbox` y si hacen match con lo que recibes en el controlador.

Comment: también puede afectar el uso de la t mayuscula en la palabra true del if?

Comment: ¿Has intentado lo que dices? Sucede que los checkboxes no marcados no se envían, para comprobar esto, crea un formulario en HTML común y silvestre, en un POST o en un GET de un formulario, recibe todos los valores de checkboxes, mira si hay alguno no marcado. Si te fijas con detenimiento, se renderiza un hidden field por cada Checkbox, ahí es como se manda el valor. Veo y confirmo que recién estás iniciando con MVC, no sé si te he sugerido antes, revisa este workshop que hice tiempo atrás: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY tiene buen fundamento del tema. Saludos.